# IOptions Custom Value Converter string to string[]

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an IConfiguration config section key-value item that represents a list of strings e.g.

```
"CustomOptions:Names":"value1||value2||value3"
```

I want to convert this item to a custom options class

```
class CustomOptions
{
    public string[] Names { set; get; }
}
```

I wonder if there I can somehow plug in a custom value converter for this item that would parse the delimited string into an array when the options object is bound to the config section item.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

I tried IConfigureOptions but i do not want to expose multiple properties on my Options object.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I injected `IConfiguration` in `IConfigureOptions` and updated the `string[]` property with the failed value binding:

```
internal class UpdateCustomOptions : IConfigureOptions<CustomOptions>
{
    public UpdateCustomOptions(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Configure(CustomOptions options)
    {
        var customOptionsSection = _configuration.GetRequiredSection(CustomOptions.Custom);

        var namesRawValue = sec.GetValue<string>(nameof(CustomOptions.Names));

        options.Names = namesRawValue.SplitCompositePropertyValueWithDelimiters(); // custom extension method
    }
}

services
    .AddOptions();

services
    .AddOptions<CustomOptions>()
    .Bind(configuration.GetRequiredSection(CustomOptions.Custom))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart();

services
    .AddSingleton<
        IConfigureOptions<CustomOptions>,
        UpdateCustomOptions>();
```